# Home and back buttons not working in android emulator pixel 2 and pixel 3 api

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I am using flutter for developing a mobile app, I want to switch on the dark mode of the emulator, but I am unable to perform any touch operations outside the app screen, the scroll down window on the emulator as well as the home buttons are not working

[image: emulator]

Comment: if possible add a screenshot or somethinng, as your question is bit unclear

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvL2UA0DHYkHfLQMuuWHnxYf_XqgeouG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to wipe data of the emulators and restart it from **Android Studio** > **Tools** > **ADV Manager** > **Action**  > **Wipe data**

Answer (score 4):

Go to AVD Manager and do a 'Cold boot'

[image]